# Popup window in Telerik MVC Grid without using Ajax

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, popup, telerik

In telerik mvc grid i want to display some data in popup window when i click on a link button. But not using Ajax. Below is the code i am using but it is not working. Any help is appreciated

@section JavaScript{

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(function () {

        $(".lnkShortCodeAndKeyword").click(

            function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var WShortCodeAndKeyword = $.telerik.window.create({

                    name: "ShortcodesWindow",
                    title: "Shortcodes",
                    contentUrl: $(this).attr('href'),
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    scrollable: true,
                    width: 960,
                    height: 600,
                    onClose: function () {
                      destruir(this);
                    }

                }).data('tWindow').center();
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the Window component anywhere on your View (by using Html.Telerik().Window() for example) you will have to manually add the [required JavaScript files](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-required-javascript-files.html) when you define your ScriptRegistrar. Normally, if you declare the components on the page the ScriptRegistrar takes care of everything for you, but if you just try to create this on the client-side you will have to do something along the following lines:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.js").Add("telerik.draganddrop.js").Add("telerik.window.js").Combined(true).Compress(true)))
```

As you can see I just manually defined the JavaScript files I wanted to load. Keep in mind to not add the "min" suffix as the ScriptRegistrar takes care of this as well (.min.js will only be used in production code and not debug).